# Tex different symbols. Integral

Tags: math-mode, symbols, integral

I can write the equations using the
\begin{equation}
y=x^2+x
\end{equation}
But how can I type the integral symbol in Tex? For example, for I=integral of something dx?

Comment: `\int`  see `texdoc symbols`

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle, also I found the block

Comment: \begin{gather*}

Comment: \end{gather*} , but no suitable library (userpackage) for its usage

Comment: Please don't add unrelated questions in comments. gather is from `amsmath` any tutorial that showed you gather should have shown amsmath being used

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, @DavidCarlisle